# How to get javascript bytecode from C++ using V8 Engine

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, embedded-v8

I have a following JavaScript code:

```
class Contract {

// constructor
constructor() {

    // dynamic data
    this.str = '';
    this.count = 0; 
}

// update function
update(_value){
    this.str = _value;
    this.count++; 
   }
}
```

How can I get bytecode and state of virtual machine using V8 engine?

Answer (score 1):

Bytecode is not exposed on V8's C++ API.

For human inspection, you can dump it to stdout by using the `--print-bytecode` flag.

If you're willing to modify V8 for your purposes, you can e.g. look for occurrences of `FLAG_print_bytecode` in the source to see how the bytecode can be accessed.

Comment: Thank you. I can parse javascript with V8's C++ to C++ object and get access to properties. So there should be a way for accessing property bytcode

Comment: Internally, there's `SharedFunctionInfo::HasBytecodeArray()` and `SharedFunctionInfo::GetBytecodeArray()`, but as I said, these are not exposed on the embedder API. What do you need the bytecode for?

Comment: Sorry as I understand this APIs is not public ?

Comment: I just need to get the byte code and the state of the virtual machine after each call. I mean to have some C++ object which contains byte code. Not just printing

Comment: Correct, there's no way to access bytecode via the public API. It's an internal implementation detail. Sorry.